# JavaScript Countdown timer with returned value after every interval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a countdown timer that returns the current countdown value from the function. So far I have managed to write the countdown function. It counts down but the function returns undefined. How can I modify the code to return the countdown value?

```js
const startTimer = (duration, onlySeconds) => {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;
  const interval = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    if (timer-- === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    console.log('seconds', seconds)
    return !onlySeconds ? minutes + ":" + seconds : seconds;
  }, 1000);
};

console.log('You will be logged out in ', startTimer(3, true))
```

Comment: You don't, really. You do the same thing you're doing with the first `console.log()`, but you update the page instead.

Comment: are you expecting it to return multiple times?

Comment: @PaulRooney. Yes, I was expecting it to return the data every 1 second

Comment: That's not how return works. It just returns once then its finished. You need to use asynchronous mechanisms like callbacks or promises. The answers provided so far seem pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return from the asynchronous `setInterval` callback and expect to access that returned value. Instead, I might recommend passing a `logger` function to which you can pass the amount of time remaining. In that function, you can do whatever you want with that time. Here's a version that just does some console logging.

```js
const startTimer = (duration, onlySeconds, logger) => {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;
  const interval = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    if (timer-- === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    
    const time = !onlySeconds ? minutes + ":" + seconds : seconds;
    logger(time);
  }, 1000);
};

const logger = (time) => {
  console.log('You will be logged out in ' + time);
}

startTimer(300, false, logger)
```

Answer (score 1):

it is much simplier and direct to the point

```js
const startTimer = (duration, onlySeconds) => {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds; 
  const interval = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
    if (timer-- === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    console.log('You will be logged out in '+ (!onlySeconds ? minutes + ":" + seconds : seconds));
  }, 1000);
};
startTimer(3, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a different strategy might be in order.

```js
class Countdown {
  constructor() {
    this._init();
  }
  _init(restart=false) {
    this.target = undefined;
    this.running = false;
    this.terminate = false;
    if(!restart) {
      this.ms = undefined;
      this.tick = [];
      this.done = [];
    }
  }
  // Set a callback that is called every second. `fn(remaining)`
  ontick(fn) {
    this.tick.push(fn);
  }
  // Set a callback that is called when the countdown ends. `fn()`
  ondone(fn) {
    this.done.push(fn);
  }
  // Start countdown with duration in milliseconds
  start(ms) {
    const now = performance.now();
    if(this.running) throw new Exception('Countdown already running.');
    this.running = true;
    this.ms = ms;
    this.target = now + ms;
    this.update = () => {
      const now = performance.now();
      if(this.terminate) {
        this._init();
        return;
      }
      const remaining = this.target - now;
      if(remaining > 100) {
        setTimeout(this.update, remaining % 1000);
        this.tick.forEach(fn => fn(remaining));
      }
      else {
        this.done.forEach(fn => fn());
        this._init();
      }
    };
    setTimeout(this.update, this.target % 1000);
  }
  // Restart a running countdown. Optionally provide a new duration.
  restart(ms=this.ms) {
    const now = performance.now();
    if(!this.running) throw new Exception('Countdown not running.');
    this.ms = ms;
    this.target = now + ms;
  }
  // Stop a running countdown.
  stop() {
    if(!this.running) throw new Exception('Countdown not running.');
    this.terminate = true;
  }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```js
const countdown = new Countdown();
countdown.ontick(remaining => {
  console.log('Remaining:', remaining, 'ms');
});
countdown.ondone(() => {
  console.log('Countdown completed.');
});
countdown.start(15*60*1000); // 15 minutes
```

If you want to restart a running countdown:

```js
countdown.restart(5*60*1000); // Update target duration to 5 minutes and restart
countdown.restart(); // Use previous duration and restart
```

If you want to cancel the countdown:

```js
countdown.stop();
```